# Open a custom dialog on browser window/tab close

Tags: jquery, javascript

I am trying to add a survey confirmation box with Ok/Cancel on browser window/tab close.
I need to redirect user to survey link on Ok button click.

Trying to implement the same with below code.

```
var leave_message = 'Wait! Would you like to respond to a quick Survey?'

function bye(e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;   
    e.cancelBubble = true;

    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    e.returnValue = leave_message;

    if (confirm(leave_message)) {
        window.open("www.surveylink.com");
    }
}

window.onbeforeunload = bye;
```

Please suggest above code is not working.

Comment: use var ans=confirm(leave_message);   if (ans==true){//redirect}

Comment: It's not possible to execute any code on window/tab closing, it's a security violation. Adware used to do this to prevent you from getting rid of their ads.

Comment: You are not going to get the answer ever ,Bcoz its NOT POSSIBLE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own

Comment: @PratikJoshi Slightly contradictory to your original comment, no?

Comment: @RGraham , i gave him solution

Answer (score 1):

Use this to force your users to your site ,This is what you can do Most anything other than that is not possible.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
                      window.open("http://www.surveylink.com");
      return 'Do you really want to leave?' ;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`onbeforeunload` is not a regular event. A dialog asking you to stay on the page is casted if you return a string in the `onbeforeunload` event handler. If the user clicks on the "Stay on page" button in that dialog, unloading of the page is aborted. (More details at, for example, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload)

My approach to that problem would be to set a variable that indicates that the page began unloading and then checking that variable regularly to determine if the unloading was aborted:

```
(function () {
    var triedToUnload = false;
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        triedToUnload = true;
        return "Wait! Would you like to respond to a quick Survey?";
    };
    window.setInterval(function () {
        if (triedToUnload) {
            window.open("www.surveylink.com");
        }
    }, 500);
}());
```